# Java jswing arboles

Tags: java

Quería agregar de un combobox el titulo de una canción en formato .mp3 replicando la misma por todos los nodos de un JTree siendo el Jtree una estructura como la siguiente
ListasYCanciones
LISTA 1
cancion1.mp3
cancion2.mp3
LISTA 2
cancion3.mp3
La cosa es que encontré cosas con la clase DefaultMutableTreeNode que tiene el método add pero no doy encontrado la forma exacta de hacerlo

Si por ejemplo me pasan cancion4.mp3 esta debe aparecer en LISTA 1 y LISTA 2
y de haber duplicados eliminarlos (q solo aparezca 1 vez)
Me gustaría a poder ser q la solución no fuera de forma recursiva
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado y los problemas que has tenido: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.